# Qt Localization QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, localization

My project folder is currently setup like this:

```
   -root
   ---[source files]
   ---Translations
   ------app_en.ts
   ------app_en.qm
   ------app_fr.ts
   ------app_fr.qm
   ------app_jp.ts
   ------app_jp.qm
```

My .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2014-03-18T15:15:40
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = TestApp
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp
TRANSLATIONS=Translations/app_en.ts\
             Translations/app_fr.ts\
             Translations/app_jp.ts
CODECFORSRC   = UTF-8

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

In my main.cpp I try to force the translation to JP:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTranslator translator;
    translator.load("app_jp");
    a.installTranslator(&translator);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But the main window still appears in English. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the documentation, but how do we force a certain local for the application?
My build output folder has the .qm files in it (I copied them in the root of the build output folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably you provided translation but it is not marked as finished. Check `app_jp.ts` (it is a xml) you will have entries with `type="unfinished"`. Clear this flag.
Probably you can do this also from Qt Linguist tool (I don't remember where is this option).

Check [this tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/linguist-hellotr.html).

Also add some logs (to verify that translator was properly loaded):

```
bool translatorLoaded = translator.load("app_jp");
if (!translatorLoaded)
    qWarrning("Problem loading translation file");
```

Comment: I did mark them as complete, when I did add a qWarning I could never get it to be true:
http://pastebin.com/L3L6TMTq

Comment: if it never returns true so this means that those *.qm files can't be found. I'm guessing that you use Qt creator with "Build in different place" option checked. Make sure that those files are in same place where executable file (or disable "build in different place").

Comment: added the qm files to an embedded resource and works fine now